# Is it possible to loop through the mysql table rows and check columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops

I have a "matrix" table with the following columns filled in.

```
matrix_id, user_id, position_1, position_2, position_3
   1          1        1982        2251       5841
   2          2        6204         0          0
   3          3          0          0          0
   4          4          0          0          0
```

I basically want to do the following.

1. Find a row with the lowest user_id and that has an empty position.
2. In the example above, that would be user_id 2 and position_2.
3. I update the row with a query.
4. I then move on to the next next empty position. Since user_id 2 still has an empty position_3, I update the row again with a query.
5. Since that row is complete, I move on to the next highest user_Id that has empty positions. In this case, it's user_id 3 and then user_id 4 the one after that.

I know I can do all of the above if I know what the user_id is. But assume in this case, I have no clue what the user_ids are.  How would the queries look then?

Here is what I have so far.

```
$find_user = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM matrix WHERE user_id > :user_id");
$find_user->bindValue(':user_id', 0);
$find_user->execute();
$result_user = $find_user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($result_user) > 0) {
  foreach($result_user as $row) {
    $matrix_id              = $row['matrix_id'];
    $user_id                = $row['user_id'];
    $position_1               = $row['position_1'];
    $position_2               = $row['position_2'];
    $position_3               = $row['position_3'];
  }
} else {
  $errors[] = 'User Id not found in Matrix.';
} 

$update_user = $db->prepare("UPDATE matrix SET position_2 = :position_2 WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$update_user->bindValue(':position_2', 1564;
$update_user->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
if($update_user->execute()) {}
```

Comment: What do you consider EMPTY to be? `''` or `NULL` or what else?

Comment: I consider empty to be "0". That's how the table is. All the empty positions are listed as 0 automatically. I should update my original table so it's not confusing.

Comment: Do all the new values get set to `1564`

Comment: Best advice would be to fix this broken design

Comment: No, all the new values would be unique.  "Strawberry", please inform how I can fix this broken design?

Comment: Define UNIQUE. Are we adding 1 to a value each time we make an update?

Comment: For this demonstration purposes, yes assume that we are adding 1 to a value each time we make an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should go through all your users from smallest user_id to largest.

For each user it will check the relevant columns in order and apply a new value to the empty ones.

```
$new_val = 1999;

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM matrix ORDER BY user_id");
$users = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($users) > 0) {

    // prepare all the possible queries
    // make use of prepare once execute many times
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `matrix` SET `position_1` = :pos WHERE `user_id` = :id");
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `matrix` SET `position_2` = :pos WHERE `user_id` = :id");
    $stmt3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `matrix` SET `position_3` = :pos WHERE `user_id` = :id");

    foreach($users as $user) {
        if ( $user['$position_1'] == 0 ) {
            $stmt1->execute( array(':pos'=>++$new_val,':id'=>$user['user_id']) );
        }
        if ( $user['$position_2'] == 0 ) {
            $stmt1->execute( array(':pos'=>++$new_val,':id'=>$user['user_id']) );

        }
        if ( $user['$position_3'] == 0 ) {
            $stmt1->execute( array(':pos'=>++$new_val,':id'=>$user['user_id']) );
        }
    }
} else {
  $errors[] = 'User Id not found in Matrix.';
}
```

You could reduce the rows to process by changing the query a bit to only find users with columns to fix

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * 
                    FROM matrix 
                    WHERE position_1 = 0 
                       OR position_2 = 0 
                       OR position_3 = 0 
                    ORDER BY user_id");
```

Comment: This is great. I will give a shot with my original code. Thank you so much.

Comment: So I tried your code above. I seem to get the error "User Id not found in Matrix". So it seems like "$result->num_rows > 0" is not returning any records. Are you sure the "$result" query is correct? If it is to find the row count, then would you not use "COUNT(*)" in the query?  Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I based my answer on your question. Basically this bit `SELECT * FROM matrix WHERE user_id > :user_id` so if `user_id` does not exist what is it called

Comment: Hi, here's a link to my full code to give you a better picture. I used your method to do it. I tested it. It doesn't insert just 1 user. If there are 20 empty positions, it will insert 20 new users and update those 20 positions with those new users.  https://paste.ofcode.org/xLF5qnmy2gPu73FHUKJQ7H  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Also that entire code is based on this matrix model. http://pasteboard.co/BYTZF7nYw.jpg

Comment: I don't get any error message with the code I showed you in the link.  It processes fine. It just updates all the empty positions in all the rows with the same user, all at the same time.  Which is of course not what I want. But I do get an that error(User Id not found in Matrix.) if I use your "$result" query as you wrote it.

Comment: Ok I think I see the issue. Amended code, see line 4 and 5, I swapped them and amended the if (count()){`

Comment: I swapped them, but I still get the error. Actually I made a slight mistake.  You are using "$result = $db->query". I was using "$result = $db->prepare".  Yes it works now. I do not get the error anymore. But the issue is the same. It updates all positions at the same time and adds the same amount of users to the matrix table.

Comment: For eg. There are 7 users. They have 50 empty positions. Once I sign up, it will fill those 50 positions with the new user id. It will also insert 50 new users rows with the same user id. So something is going on with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

important thing here, is that you are working with the row, not columns
so check all the prerequisites and update the row.

```
$find_user = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM matrix order by user_id asc");
$find_user->execute();
$result_user = $find_user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach($result_user as $row) {
    $matrix_id  = $row['matrix_id'];
    $user_id    = $row['user_id'];
    $position_1 = $row['position_1'];
    $position_2 = $row['position_2'];
    $position_3 = $row['position_3'];
  }
 $str = ''
 if (!$position_2){
   $str = "position_2 = :position_2"
 } else if (!$position_2 && !$position_3){
   $str = "position_2 = :position_2 and position_3 = :position_3"
 }    


$update_user = $db->prepare("UPDATE matrix SET " . $str . " WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$update_user->bindValue(':position_2', 1564);
$update_user->bindValue(':position_3', 1564);
$update_user->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
if($update_user->execute()) {}
```

Also, get all the rows in the matrix table ordered by used_id and process every row, depending on your condition.

Comment: I think `asc` not `desc`

Comment: `$srt` =/= `$str`

Comment: What about empty `position_1`

Comment: thnx guys, position_1 is not in the conditions

Comment: My question, if I under hundreds of users with 3 positions each, in the table, how would that work?

Comment: same way, if it would be in millions, then it might be slow.